# set attribute to qstandarditem in pyqt5

Tags: pyqt5

Basically I have a QTableView and I use View Model for the table and then append to model as following:

```
for i in range(0, 10):
    self.tableViewModel.appendRow([QStandardItem("%s" % ("Hello")), QStandardItem("%s" % ("How are you?"))])
```

I want to set `i` as an attribute to each row where later I could access to understand which is which.

Is there a way to set an attribute to QStarndardItem?

Comment: Isn't the `item.row()` enough? If not, use a custom role (a basic integer constant with value >= `QtCore.Qt.UserRole`), and then `item.setData(MyCustomRole, i)` or `item.data(MyCustomRole)`.